# The parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm having a problem with my code:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    list.Items.Clear()

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM borrow where (Department LIKE '%" & TextBox2.Text & "%')"
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    con.Open()


    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rd.HasRows = True Then
        While rd.Read()

            Dim listview As New ListViewItem

            listview.Text = rd("ID").ToString
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Department").ToString)
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Purpose").ToString)
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Items_Details").ToString)
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Requested_by").ToString)
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Approved_by").ToString)
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Date").ToString)
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Status").ToString)
            listview.SubItems.Add(rd("Date_Returned").ToString)

            list.Items.Add(listview)

        End While
    End If
    con.Close()
```

Once I typed in the string in the textbox to search for an item I get this error:

> The parameterized query '(@Parameter1 nvarchar(4000))SELECT * FROM
>   borrow where (Departme' expects the parameter '@Parameter1', which was
>   not supplied.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

If you pass null value to parameter,you will get this error even after you add the parameter
so try to check the value and if it null then use DBNull.Value

This will work

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar)

If (TextBox2.Text = Nothing) Then
    cmd.Parameters("@Department").Value = DBNull.Value
Else
    cmd.Parameters("@Department").Value = TextBox2.Text
End If
```

This will convert the null values from the object layer to DBNull values that are acceptable to the database.

Comment: Shorthand: cmd.Parameters("@Department").Value = (object)TextBox2.Text ?? DBNull.Value;

Comment: This works for me. The .Add has been depreciated. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", (object)TextBox2.Text ?? DBNull.Value);

Comment: `.Add(String, Object)` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Object_), `Add(String, SqlDbType)` is not. This answer (or the subsequent comments) do not use a deprecated method.

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=netframework-4.8): "Use DBNull.Value instead of null, to indicate a null value."

Answer (score 17):

**Your website is in serious danger of being hacked.**

Read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [how to prevent it in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx)

Your query problem is the least of your concerns right now.

But.....

@Misnomer's solution is close but not quite there:

Change your query to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM borrow where (Department LIKE '%@DepartmentText%')"
```

and add parameters this way (or the way that @Misnomer does):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentText",TextBox2.Text)
```

The important difference is that you need to change your CommandText.

Comment: hi i've tnx.. ive changed my code but still im getting the error.. cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM borrow where (Department LIKE '%@DepartmentText%')"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentText", TextBox2.Text)  error "The parameterized query '(@Parameter1 nvarchar(4000),@Department varchar(8000),@Departmen' expects the parameter '@Parameter1', which was not supplied."

Comment: I suspect your error is being thrown from somewhere else.  Can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Your answer misses the intent of `'%' + @DepartmentText + '%'`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on and simplifying ravidev's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530911/1152054):

The VB.NET shorthand is:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", IF(TextBox2.Text, DBNull.Value))
```

The C# shorthand is:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", (object)TextBox2.Text ?? DBNull.Value)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) like this -

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar)
cmd.Parameters("@Department").Value = TextBox2.Text
```

and change your command text to what @Abe Miessler does he is right i just thought you will figure it out.

Comment: I dont know why....but i get the feeling that you have a datatype issue here...or something...seeing the `Departmen` i feel you dont have enough characters alloted or something...

Comment: hi i've tnx.. ive changed my code but still im getting the error.. cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM borrow where (Department LIKE '%@DepartmentText%')" cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepartmentText", SqlDbType.VarChar) cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentText", TextBox2.Text) error "The parameterized query '(@Parameter1 nvarchar(4000),@Department varchar(8000),@Departmen' expects the parameter '@Parameter1', which was not supplied.

Comment: The problem in this case is most likely that the parameter value should include the '% %' and not wrapping the parameter in quotes.

Comment: it is ineresting that such form doesn't help : cmd.Add(new SqlParameter("@Department", SqlDbType.VarChar){Value=textBox.Department, IsNullable=true});

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing from a DataGridView control to your database, make sure there is no empty row. Set 'Allow User to add Rows' to false; it truncates the unnecessary last empty row.