# I am getting the "Must declare the scalar variable "@Val1"" error when inserting the record using C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, odbc

When I am running the following code

```
        if (NewButtonClicked == true) {
            string sql = "SELECT MAX(location_id)+1 FROM locations";
            OdbcCommand my_odbc_cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, my_odbc_connection);
            OdbcDataReader my_data_reader;
            int new_id = 0;
            my_data_reader = my_odbc_cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (my_data_reader.HasRows) 
            {
                my_data_reader.Read();
                new_id = (int)my_data_reader[0];
            }
            my_data_reader.Close();
            textBoxLocationID.Text = new_id.ToString();
            sql = "INSERT INTO locations (location_id,location,latitude,longitude,city,"
                + "state_province,country,continent) VALUES (@Val1,'@Val2',@Val3,@Val4,'@Val5','@Val6','@Val7','@Val8')";
            my_odbc_cmd.Connection = my_odbc_connection;
            my_odbc_cmd.CommandText = sql;
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", new_id);
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val2", textBoxName.Text);
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val3", textBoxLatitude.Text);
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val4", textBoxLongitude.Text);
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val5", textBoxCity.Text);
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val6", textBoxState_Province.Text);
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val7", textBoxCountry.Text);
            my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val8", textBoxContinent.Text);

            my_odbc_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            my_odbc_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

It is giving me "Must declare the scalar variable "@Val1"" when the execution is reached at:

```
my_odbc_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How can I solve this error. Can anyone help me? Database used at the backend is SQL Server 2008 R2. I am using the ODBC connection to connect to the database.

Comment: Please retag your question with the appropriate database system you are using...

Comment: What is the value of `new_id` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6778595/151488

Comment: I have edited the code above see there what the new_id is?

Answer (score 4):

This probably means that `new_id` is `null`. Parameters with a value of `null` **are not sent**. You need to pass `DBNull.Value` instead. Crazy but true.

```
my_odbc_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Val1", ((object)new_id) ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Also: `'@Val2'` (and similar) are very wrong. You almost certainly mean just `@Val2`, no quotes.

Comment: +1 for crazy, why are you casting to an object btw? I always do `new_id ?? DbNull.Value` or is there something to it?

Comment: @Silvermind because I can't see how `new_id` is declared. If it is declared as `object`, then yes: `new_id ?? DBNull.Value` is fine. If it is declared as `int?` then what you suggest won't compile (`Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'System.DBNull'`). What I suggest will. I will, however, update with something simpler - a middle ground. Happier now?

Comment: I was not going for a simpler approach and my state of happiness might be a little higher, but I just honestly made a mistake for the sake of dealing with a lot of weak types in this same context all day ;) Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

According to the "Working with Parameter Placeholders" section on the MSDN page [Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `Odbc` datasource supports only positional parameters via `?` in the query text, *not* named parameters (such as `@Val1`), which are supported only by `SqlClient`.

Additionally as Marc Gravell indicates, you shouldn't be quoting the parameters in your query.

Try changing your SQL to:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO locations (location_id,location,latitude,longitude,city,"
            + "state_province,country,continent) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: How can I assign a value to a parameter ?.

Comment: The way you're adding parameters currently should be fine, but the relation of the `?` to the parameter is by the order in which they appear in the query (so the first `?` takes its value from the first parameter added, etc.)