# The parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied c# SQL

Tags: c#, sql

I am new in SQL and C# and I encountered this SQL error.

> The parameterized query '(@pid nvarchar(4000),@desc
>   nvarchar(4000),@cat nvarchar(4000),@p' expects the parameter '@pid',
>   which was not supplied.

I really need help. Thanks!

```
 public void InsertRecord()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PRODUCTS VALUES (@pid, @desc, @cat, @price, @scode)", myCon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", productID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", description);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", category);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scode", supplierCode);//corrected the "key codes"

        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();//added these lines of codes
    }
```

Comment: is productID null by any chance?

Comment: You are using the INSERT syntax that requires all the fields values to be passed for insertion, do you have just 5 fields in your table PRODUCTS?

Comment: I can't enable the productID textbox. I don't know why.

Comment: I mean the textbox is enabled but I can't type anything into it.

Comment: Windows Forms Application in C#

Comment: I can't recall if this is the correct terminology, but check whether that textbox is marked as read-only

Comment: I can now already type at the textbox. So the product id is not null anymore. But the problem is still the same.

Comment: Are all your table fields really meant to be `nvarchars`? Seems a little strange to me to have a product ID field be a full text but maybe there is a reason.

Comment: I don't know why it shows nvarchar there. In my table, I defined those as varchar,varchar,varchar,decimal, and varchar

Comment: what about trying to add parameters like this instead. cmd.Parameters.Add("@pid", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters("@pid").Value = productID;

Comment: Brandon.Staley I tried sir, sadly nothing happened. The error still occurs :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [The parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865982/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must check every parameters if they are null. If they are, you have to pass `DBNull.Value`.

```
SqlParameter pidParam = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pidParam", productID);
if (productID == null)
{
    pidParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

source: [The parameterized query ..... expects the parameter '@units', which was not supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448403/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-units-which-was-not-supp)