# The parameterized query ..... expects the parameter '@units', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I'm getting this exception:

> The parameterized query '(@Name nvarchar(8),@type nvarchar(8),@units nvarchar(4000),@rang' expects the parameter '@units', which was not supplied.

My code for inserting is:

```
public int insertType(string name, string type, string units = "N\\A", string range = "N\\A", string scale = "N\\A", string description = "N\\A", Guid guid = new Guid())
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Type(name, type, units, range, scale, description, guid) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@Name, @type, @units, @range, @scale, @description, @guid) ";
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", units);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@range", range);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scale", scale);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guid", guid);
        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

The exception was a surprise because I'm using the `AddWithValue` function and making sure I added a default parameters for the function.

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Why does the error message complain about `@units` rather than `@Name`, which appears first?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I suppose it doesn't have to look for them in the order they are supplied.

Comment: @Yogevnn Ahh, `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", @name)` should be `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name)` etc.

Comment: @Yogevnn can you show here script for creation [Type] table?

Comment: @Yogevnn I suspect `AddWithValue` is guessing something wrong. Try using the [SqlParameter Constructor (String, SqlDbType, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: ghost - I created it from the editor, what would you like to know about the table?

@GrantWinney I think it may be empty, while i'm checking it, let's assume it is, how can i fix that?

Comment: @GrantWinney yes they are all empty (all the one's with default)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865982/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SqlParameter unitsParam = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", units);
if (units == null)
{
    unitsParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

And you must check all other parameters for null value. If it null you must pass `DBNull.Value` value.

Comment: I dont think it could be null because OP has the parameter like this `string units = "N\\A"`

Comment: It could, because you can call method like this `insertType(null, null, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: @GrantWinney Apparently that is not how it works. The parameter has to be omitted from the calling code rather than set to `null`. [Named and Optional Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Comment: @GrantWinney Defaults don't work like that. They only apply when you don't pass *anything* (if you omit the argument altogether). If you pass anything at all, even `null`, then what you pass is what the callee sees.

Comment: A shorter way to write this is `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", (object)units ?? DBNull.Value)`.

Comment: Why `AddWithValue` does not check null in the first place? ( ͡° ل͜ ͡°)

Answer (score 51):

Here's a way using the null-coalescing operator:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", units ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@range", range ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scale", scale ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description ?? (object)DBNull.Value);
```

Or for more strict type checking:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@units", SqlDbType.Int).Value = units ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@range", SqlDbType.Int).Value = range ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@scale", SqlDbType.Int).Value = scale ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = description ?? (object)DBNull.Value;
```

The operator also be chained:

```
int?[] a = { null, null, 1 };
Console.WriteLine(a[0] ?? a[1] ?? a[2]);
```

Answer (score 5):

This extension class was useful to me a couple of times so far, for those issues:

```
public static class DbValueExtensions
{
    // Used to convert values coming from the db
    public static T As<T>(this object source)
    {
        return source == null || source == DBNull.Value
            ? default(T)
            : (T)source;
    }

    // Used to convert values going to the db
    public static object AsDbValue(this object source)
    {
        return source ?? DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

You would normally use it in two scenarios. First, when creating parameters for your query:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "@username", username.AsDbValue() },
    { "@password", password.AsDbValue() },
    { "@birthDate", birthDate.AsDbValue() },
};
```

or when parsing the SqlReader values:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    yield return new UserInfo(
        reader["username"].As<string>(),
        reader["birthDate"].As<DateTime>(),
        reader["graduationDate"].As<DateTime?>(),
        reader["nickname"].As<string>()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (name == null ? "" : name));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a method to be reused with multiple parameters:

```
public void NullorEmptyParameter(QC.SqlCommand command, string at, string value)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(at, DBNull.Value);
    }
    else
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(at, value);
}
```

And then you can reuse it for as many commands and params:

```
NullorEmptyParameter(command, "@Idea_ID", Idea_ID);
NullorEmptyParameter(command, "@Opportunities_or_Idea", Opportunities_or_Idea);
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever value you might want to pass (empty string, DBNull.Value, or etc), the following pattern worked for me.

```
public static class CommandHelpers
{
    public static SqlParameter AddWithValue<T>(this SqlParameterCollection p, string at, object value)
    {
        SqlParameter output;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            if (value is null || value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                output = p.AddWithValue(at, "");
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((string)value)) 
            {
                output = p.AddWithValue(at, "");
            }
            else
            {
                output = p.AddWithValue(at, value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (value is null || value == DBNull.Value)
            {
                output = p.AddWithValue(at, "");
            }
            else
            {
                output = p.AddWithValue(at, value);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue<DateTime>("@Date_Entered", DateTime.Now);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue<string>("@Entered_by", UserName);
```

I hope that gets someone started.  In this variation I passed in a type because you can't find a type of a null object.

Answer (score -1):

<sub>Migrating OP's solution from the question to an answer:</sub>

> The problem was that the some parameters were empty Strings (that override the default)
>
> This is the working code:
>
> ```
> public int insertType(string name, string type, string units = "N\\A", string range = "N\\A", string scale = "N\\A", string description = "N\\A", Guid guid = new Guid())
>    {
>        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
>        {
>            connection.Open();
>            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
>            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Type(name, type, units, range, scale, description, guid) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES (@Name, @type, @units, @range, @scale, @description, @guid) ";
>            command.Connection = connection;
>            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
>            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", type);
>
>            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(units))
>            {
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", DBNull.Value); 
>            }
>            else
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@units", units);
>            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(range))
>            {
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@range", DBNull.Value);
>            }
>            else
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@range", range);
>            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(scale))
>            {
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scale", DBNull.Value);
>            }
>            else
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scale", scale);
>            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
>            {
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", DBNull.Value);
>            }
>            else
>                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
>                     
>            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guid", guid);
>
>            return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
>        }
>    }
> ```