# Value not being set in c# SQL command

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have written a code that will read in a txt file and parse through the data and assign the correct numbers into the correct columns of a SQL table. The problem I am having is that I implemented a Merge so that the data from different rows in the txt file will show up in different columns but the same rows in the SQL table. However, I am now getting an issue that my variable is not being set, but it was before I implemented the merge. This is my code:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record.RESORT);
    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
    // This allows us to split what column a row goes into based on whether it is a day and what SUB_GRP_1 it is
    string Heading = record.HEADING_2;
    string Group = record.SUB_GRP_1;
    string column;
    if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC")
    {
        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC_WO_CH")
    {
        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM")
    {
        column = "ADR";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM_WO_CH")
    {
        column = "ADR_minus_Comp_and_House";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOMREV_AVL_ROOMS_MINUS_OOO")
    {
        column = "Revenue_per_Available_Room_minus_OOO";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "TOTAL_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Total_Revenue";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOM_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Room_Revenue";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "FOOD_BEV_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Food_And_Beverage_Revenue";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OTHER_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Other_Revenue";

    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "PHYSICAL_ROOMS")
    {
        column = "Total_Rooms_in_Hotel";

    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_ROOMS")
    {
        column = "Rooms_Occupied";

    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_MINUS_COMP_HU")
    {
        column = "Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House_Use";

    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "COMP_ROOMS")
    {
        column = "Complimentary_Rooms";

    }
    else
    {
        column = "";
    }




    // SQL connection. Creates connection and command and inserts the values taken from the File Helper engine into the SQL table
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection conn;


    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"MERGE [HEWreport] AS target USING (select @Property_ID as Property_ID, @val as {0}) AS source ON (target.Property_ID = source.Property_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0}
                                    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property_ID, {0}) VALUES (source.Property_ID, source.{0});", column);
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property_ID", record.RESORT);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And this is the error I keep getting:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The parameterized query '(@Property_ID nvarchar(5),@val nvarchar(4000))MERGE [HEWreport] ' expects the parameter '@val', which was not supplied.

I know it has something to do with an error in my line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);
```

But I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Doing `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);` you add a (SQL) variable called @column to your query - you're not adding the content of your (C#) variable column..

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen so how would i add the content of my variable column

Comment: Please don't edit your question to correct the code.  Now the comments regarding the "@column" parameter make no sense.  Also, you didn't say if that edit fixed your issue, anyway.

Comment: That edit was because I had tried it where they both said column and both said val. I had tried it both ways and neither worked but when i copy and pasted my code one of them was after I had done it one way and one was after I did it the other way. That didn't fix the problem. I  was just fixing it so people didn't think that was why it wasn't working

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there is no reason for you to check `Heading == "DAY"` literally 13 times.  You can throw all of your if statements inside another if that checks `Heading`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you attached a SQL Profiler?  What is the query which is sent to the SQL Server?

The code (in general) looks correct.
The error message implies that "@val" is not provided, but the code you are showing is adding it.  It could be that `record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT` is null or has some other problem which causes the parameter not to be added, but this should throw a C# exception.

It is also possible that you are running old code, so what you copied in is different than what is being run.

If the SQL Profiler does not get you the information you need, try statically specifying the values in the C# and see what happens.

```
var sqlCommand = @"MERGE [HEWreport] AS target USING (select @Property_ID as Property_ID, @val as ColumnName) AS source ON (target.Property_ID = source.Property_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ColumnName = source.ColumnName
                                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property_ID, ColumnName) VALUES (source.Property_ID, source.ColumnName);";
cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property_ID", "215");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", "17");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

**Other Comments:**

A MERGE is overkill for an insert statement (without an UPDATE or DELETE).  Instead use something like:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [HEWreport] WHERE Property_ID = @Property_ID)
    INSERT INTO [HEWreport] (Property_ID, <ColumnName>) VALUES (@Property_ID, @val);
```

As was indicated in the comments, `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` is not recommended.  Instead, create a `SqlParmeter`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Property_ID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = record.RESORT});
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@val", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 250) { Value = record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT});
```

Documentation:
[SqlParameter Constructor (String, SqlDbType)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f14f0z(v=vs.110).aspx)
[SqlParameter Constructor (String, SqlDbType, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hex23w80(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when record.RESORT and/or record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT is null. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448403/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-units-which-was-not-supp) for a similar issue.