# ExecuteNonQuery() SQLException Incorrect Syntax Near ',' WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, ado.net, radgridview

I am trying to run a SQL command that saves all the items in a column back to a database table.  The users enter in this information, and when they close the window the newly entered information should get saved back to a database.  I am attempting to do this using a SQL connection and SQL command.  The issue is when I enter in the information and close the window, I get an error at the `comm.ExecuteNonQuery()` that says 'Incorrect syntax near ','.' I am unsure exactly where in my command there is an issue considering I entered my syntax in a online SQL syntax checker and everything came out fine.  Here is my code for the `Window_Closing` event below:

```
public void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var checkNoValue = ((DataProperties)gridView.SelectedItem).Check_No;
        var checkDateValue = ((DataProperties)gridView.SelectedItem).Check_Date;

        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        string connstring = "server = testserver; database = test; user = someusername; password = somepassword";
        conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        conn.Open();
        comm = new SqlCommand("insert into DeductionInfo (" + gridView.Columns["checkNo"] + ", " + gridView.Columns["checkDate"] + ") values (" + checkNoValue + ", " + checkDateValue + ")", conn);

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Saved");
    }
```

I am trying to insert the new data into the DeductionInfo datatable located in my database.  I think I can sort of guess what the issue is, since I have `checkNoValue` and `checkDateValue` set to my `gridView.SelectedItem` property, however I am unsure how to set that to be each value in those specific columns (I am using Telerik's RadGridView by the way).  Keep in mind that `Check_No` is an integer and `Check_Date` is a datetime.  Am I tackling this all wrong or am I on the right track?  This is the first time I've handled SQL queries in WPF and C#, so I'm pretty new to this.  Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Try using parameters instead of creating the insert command with variables.

Comment: Side note: use `using` for disposable objects.

Comment: What are the actual names of your columns in the DeductionInfo table? These aren't dynamic...

Comment: You should read about SQL injection : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  The actual names of my columns are "Check_No", and "Check_Date" and these are defined in a separate class called "DataProperties", hense my cast for checkNoValue and checkDateValue.

Comment: I meant the actual names of columns in the table in the database, not your properties...

Comment: My apologies.  In the table it's called checkNo and checkDate, but I definitely understand the confusion.

Comment: Then it should be insert into DeductionInfo (checkNo, checkDate) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use parameters when executing dynamic SQL queries and you should always dispose `IDisposables` as soon as you are done using them.

Besides, the column names of a table in a database aren't dynamic. You need to know the actual names of these to be able to insert some data into them.

Try this:

```
public void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var checkNoValue = ((DataProperties)gridView.SelectedItem).Check_No;
    var checkDateValue = ((DataProperties)gridView.SelectedItem).Check_Date;

    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand comm;
    string connstring = "Server = testserver; Database = test; User Id = test; Password = somepassword;"
            conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
    conn.Open();
    comm = new SqlCommand("insert into DeductionInfo (checkNo, checkDate) values (@checkNoValue, @checkDateValue)", conn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkNoValue", checkNoValue);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkDateValue", checkDateValue);

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    comm.Dispose();
    conn.Dispose();

    MessageBox.Show("Saved");
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  You gave a very clear answer to this question.  Like I said, when dealing with databases and SQL Queries, I'm pretty new to it.  Even with all the research I did prior to posting this question I was not exposed to the idea of parameters.  It definitely makes a lot of sense.  I will let you know if it works.

Comment: That got rid of my initial error.  Now it says 'The parameterized query '(@checkNoValue nvarchar(4), @checkDateValue nvarchar(4000)) insert' expects the parameter '@checkDateValue', which was not supplied'.  I am not entirely sure what it is saying here...

Comment: Make sure that your checkDateValue variable contains a value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448403/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-units-which-was-not-supp

Comment: It does, although it's a DateTime value so I'm not sure if that'd affect anything.  The property in DataProperties is DateTime and the column in the datatable in the database is datetime as well.

Comment: According to the error message it's a nvarchar(4000).

Comment: Gotcha. so in my DataProperties, checkDate is a DateTime? because that is what it's set as in my database table.  I am unsure if that affects much however.  After looking at the link you posted above, using if/else statements to check for nulls did help, but another error is thrown: "into column 'claimid', table 'test.DeductionInfo'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."  This error doesn't make any sense, because I don't make any calls to my 'claimid' column which is completely separate...

Comment: Well, you need to if the DeductionInfo contains such a column. You cannot insert a new row without supplying a claimid then.

Comment: Gotcha. I guess I just got confused because Check_No and Check_Date are the only null columns, and every other column in the database will be automatically generated at a later time.  I apologize for not completely getting this, but I thank you for at least being patient haha

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proper way to dispose of your connection when it's over, and how to pass parameter to a SQL query. This will save you errors like the one you're having right now and also protect you against SQL Injection

```
string sql = "SELECT empSalary from employee where salary = @salary";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    var salaryParam = new SqlParameter("salary", SqlDbType.Money);
    salaryParam.Value = txtMoney.Text;

    command.Parameters.Add(salaryParam);
    var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

source : [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try it out.  I did a lot of research into this issue but I was never presented with the idea to use parameters.  It helps a lot.

Comment: Also make sure you add the parameters in your c# code in the same order as they appear in your query. this caused me many headaches in the past