# the parameterized query error c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, combobox, sqlconnection

When i select an item from combo box(cb_oname) and enter the order then the program crashes and give error at executenonquery().i have highlighted below 
Actually this code runs when i click the submit order button. the cb_ocat is the category of the item its data type is vnarchar(50)

```
string query = @"Insert into  dbo.orders
(OrderType,OrderID,Product_Name, Product_category,Product_Quantity,
Product_Price,Date,Discount,Order_Price,Phone) values  
(@txt_rdvalue,@txt_orderid,@cb_oname,@cb_ocat,@cb_oqty,
@txt_oprice,@Date,@txt_disc,@txt_orderprice,@txt_call)";

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_rdvalue.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_orderid.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_oname.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_ocat.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cb_oqty.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_oprice.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_disc.Text))
{
    lbl_incorrect.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Pizza Mania;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", dateTimePicker1.Value.Date));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_rdvalue", txt_rdvalue.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_orderid", Convert.ToDouble(txt_orderid.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_oname", cb_oname.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_ocat", cb_ocat.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_oqty", Convert.ToDouble(cb_oqty.SelectedItem));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_oprice", Convert.ToDouble((txt_oprice.Text)));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_disc", Convert.ToDouble(txt_disc.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_orderprice", txt_orderprice.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt_call", txt_call.Text);
            if (txt_call.Text == null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"txt_call", txt_call.Text == null);
            }



            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();// here i am getting the error that the parameterized query cb_' expects the parameter cb_ocat which was not supplied.

            //MessageBox.Show("Order Inserted");

            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: _cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"txt_call", txt_call.Text == null);_ can you explain this line?

Comment: Due to the exception you posted the selected item of cb_ocat is propably null.

Comment: @TaW that line is useless but inconsequential because txt_Call.Text will never be null

Comment: removed txt_call but doesnt ring a bell

Comment: _txt_Call.Text will never be null_ is that true for all the other params or is it just an assumption?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The parameterized query expects the parameter which was not supplied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865982/the-parameterized-query-expects-the-parameter-which-was-not-supplied)

Comment: actually i made a button and set the index of all these but i want to change only one parameter at run time that is cb_oname when i manually change it , i gives me error and when i manually change cb-ocat with cb_oname it runs perfectly

Comment: The Text property of any TextBox control is never null, an empty string but not null

Comment: @AlyGoreja do you have anything selected in the combobox cb_ocat at the moment in which you press the insert button?

Comment: yes i see a value but the problem is system is not reading that value at that moment.

Comment: actually different cb_oname have different categories(cb_ocat)

Comment: but some of these have same categories

Comment: how to make the combobox menudown clicked by code?

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint at the first line of this code and follow it looking at the values passed as parameters? Your first line should be enough to prevent entering the query code without proper values and the error (as @ManuelZelenka says) is caused by a NULL value for the SelectedItem in your AddWithValue line. This should not be possible so perhaps you need to clear your solution and rebuild all.

Answer (score 1):

am not much sure of this but

if cb_oact is string try to convert it to String
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cb_ocat", cb_ocat.SelectedItem.ToString());
Hope this works