# "Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied"

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to figure out this bug for a while now, some help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Here is my error message:
Procedure or function 'getAvailableSMSNumbers' expects parameter '@Election_ID', which was not supplied.

Here is my sql code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}getAvailableSMSNumbers
    @Election_ID nvarchar(20)       
AS  
SELECT *
FROM {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}icc_sms_phones
LEFT JOIN {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}icc_sms_elections ON sms_elections_sms_number = phones_number

WHERE sms_elections_sms_number IS NULL
OR sms_elections_id = @Election_ID

GO
```

Function:

```
Public Overrides Function getAvailableSMSNumbers(eventid As String) As IDataReader
    Dim dtable As New DataTable
    Using sqlconn As New SqlConnection(Me.ConnectionString)
        Using sqlcomm As New SqlCommand
            Using sqlda As New SqlDataAdapter
                sqlcomm.Connection = sqlconn
                sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure                           sqlcomm.CommandText=GetFullyQualifiedName("getAvailableSMSNumbers")
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Election_ID", eventid)
                sqlda.SelectCommand = sqlcomm
                sqlconn.Open()
                sqlda.Fill(dtable)
                sqlconn.Close()
                Return dtable.CreateDataReader
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Where the function is used:

```
Public Function getAvailableSMSNumbers(eventid As String) As List(Of phoneModel)
    Dim numbers As New List(Of phoneModel)
    Dim number As phoneModel

    numbers = CBO.FillCollection(Of phoneModel)(dal.getAvailableSMSNumbers(eventid))

    For Each number In numbers 'dal.getAvailableSMSNumbers(eventid).Rows
        number = New phoneModel
        With number
            .val = ("PHONES_NUMBER").ToString
            .text = String.Format("{0:# (###) ###-####}", Long.Parse(.val))
        End With
        numbers.Add(number)
    Next
    Return numbers
End Function
```

If you need anymore information, let me know, and I will add it.

Comment: Can you verify that you're actually passing valid string as `eventid` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3865982/1654818. Please compare the problem with yours and add details to differentiate them if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically occurs if the object supplied as the value of your SQL parameter is NULL, but the stored procedure does not allow null values (which yours does not).  You can set a conditional breakpoint on this line `sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Election_ID", eventid)` to make sure the `eventid` parameter is not null.

It might also be a good idea to use defensive coding, and in your getAvailableSMSNumbers function, check to make sure `eventid` is not null, and if it is, throw an exception or provide some type of feedback for the user.

Comment: So, according to your reasoning, if _eventid_ is null the parameter @Election_ID is not passed to the stored procedure?

Comment: It is either not passed, or is passed, but with a NULL value.  If you want `@Election_ID` to accepted NULLs, you'd want to declare it in your sproc as `@Election_ID nvarchar(20)  = NULL` so it has a default value.

Comment: Old answer, I know, but it helped me today. I had an object that was nothing, so the parameter was not being passed to the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can try to re-compile your stored procedure to allow `NULL` parameter :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE {databaseOwner}{objectQualifier}getAvailableSMSNumbers

    @Election_ID nvarchar(20) = NULL

AS
```

That means that the default value of your Parameter will be null in case there is no value on input. This solution will be nice in case you want to return empty datatable without error. In any other case you have to debug your VB code and understand where the issue starts.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how you are calling you procedure. When you call you need to supply the value of the procedure: For example,

```
Call get_particular_girl_from_girlsTable("Jane")
```

where get_particular_girl_from_girlsTable is the procedure and "Jane" is value for parameter GirlName.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify if

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.**StoredProcedure**
```

By default, the value is Text, expecting a SELECT, INSERT or other command text.